# URL redirect HAproxy

Tags: redirect, haproxy, adfs

I would need to use ADFS with HAPROXY.

At the moment the only problem I have is that I can’t make the redirect from https://adfsstg.xxx.com to https://adfsstg.xxx.com/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx

this is my frontend:

```
frontend adfsstg
  bind 10.129.10.3:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.pem
  mode http
  redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
  acl is_root path -i  /
  redirect code 301 location adfsstg.xxx.com/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx  if is_root
  use_backend adfsstg
```

this is my backend:

```
backend adfsstg
  balance roundrobin
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
  http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
  mode http
  http-request deny if !{ src -f /etc/haproxy/allowedoffices.acl }
  server adfsstg.xxx.com 10.129.9.144:443 check ssl verify none
```

can you help me please?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I would use this (untested)

```
frontend adfsstg
  bind 10.129.10.3:80 
  bind 10.129.10.3:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.pem
  mode http
  redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

  # path will mach also with the redirect URL 
  # because there is a '/' in the url
  # '-i' is useless because there is no uper or lower case for '/'
  # orig line "acl is_root path -i  /"
  acl is_root path_end /
  
  http-request redirect code 301 location https://adfsstg.xxx.com/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx  if is_root
  use_backend adfsstg
```